# Flex window - clicking on empty space

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

There are flex icons arranged as described in picture provided:

[image: flex icons]

Whenever user clicks somewhere in the empty space (marked red) the icon (marked 'A') gets clicked. Is this common flex issue? Any idea how to solve this?

Edit: I pasted all relevant code here. It is Flex's TileList in question

```
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"

private var systemArray : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

private function init() : void
{
    //adding icons
    systemArray.addItem({name: "Some Name1",
                             state: "classHeaderListState", toolTip: "",
                             icon: new AssetLib().classHeaderIcon32,
                             id: "entityClassesForm"});
    systemArray.addItem({name: "Some Name2",
                             state: "resourceListState", toolTip: "",
                             icon: new AssetLib().resourceIcon32, id: "resourcesForm"});

}

private function onClickList(e : Event) : void
{   
    var index : int;
    index = TileList(e.currentTarget).selectedIndex;
    if (index == -1)
        return;
    currentState = systemArray.getItemAt(index).state;
    (this.parent as Pod).title = systemArray.getItemAt(index).name;
}


<mx:State name="MenuState"
          enterState="(this.parent as Pod).title='System Tools';udfButtonPanel.visible = false;">
    <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
        <mx:TileList id="list"
                     width="100%"
                     themeColor="#ffffff"
                     height="100%"
                     dataProvider="{ systemArray }"
                     itemClick="onClickList(event)"
                     borderStyle="none"
                     />

    </mx:AddChild>
</mx:State>
```

Comment: Including an image is a good start, but in order to get an answer you need to include the code you are using, what those icons are (what as3 class/mxml tag they are) and how you add the clicking functionality.

Comment: "is this a common flex issue?" No, it isn't.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you may add a clickable area under the icons with a related MouseEvent when the user click on it nope?
Best regards.

Comment: You are right. I provided code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It seems clicking on the empty space left by flex propagates the click event to the checkbox or element you have on the flex surrounding it. This happens when the flexbox takes all the width, but align it's content on the start.

There is some workaround, the easiest ( and ugliest ) being using `width: fit-content`.

You can also use `display: inline-flex` if your parent has no specific style.